# how to get an image's tooltip, which will only appear when we mouseover it. In Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning Selenium, and i want to get the tooltip of the image printed on the selenium console,...the tooltip will only appear when we mouse over the image.. I tried to get the xpath and used actions.. but its not working..

```
         the website I am using is...(https://mayexam.cpsatexam.org/certifications/) the tooltip of the three round logo images is i am looking for
```

String xpathTooltip1 ="//*[@id="tippy-1"]/div/div[2]";

```
        String img2 = "//*[@id=\"eael-section-tooltip-bf4f6d6\"]/div/div/img";
        
        WebElement toolTIP = driver.findElement(By.xpath(img2));
        action.clickAndHold(toolTIP).moveByOffset(50, 0);
        String actTooltip = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathTooltip1)).getText();
        System.out.println("The tooltip  is " + actTooltip);
```

Comment: The website `https://mayexam.cpsatexam.org/certifications/` isn't accessible

Comment: Is it not there as a `title` attribute in your `img` tag?

Comment: no its not... i tried...Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB ya sorry they have changed the url...i cant access it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tooltips are generally part of title attribute. In this case tooltip is in 'div' tag with class 'tippy-content',

This code will work.

```
String img2 = "//*[@id=\"eael-section-tooltip-bf4f6d6\"]/div/div/img";
String xpathTooltip1 = "//div[@class='tippy-content']";


WebElement image= driver.findElement(By.xpath(img2));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(image).perform();
String actTooltip = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathTooltip1)).getText();
System.out.println("The tooltip  is " + actTooltip);
```

[image]